Find the largest integer $x$ such that $x - 6 | x^{1000} + 2$.

Find the largest integer $x$ such that $x - 6 | x^{1000} + 2$.

How would I go about solving for $x$? I am told that the answer should have just under 800 digits, so brute forcing is not possible. I know there are theorems that I can use, but I am not certain how to apply them to this problem.

Write $x^{1000}=((x-6)+6)^{1000}$

See e.g. here in the linked dupe for general methods.
